# Limit of a Function Definition (Why restrict domain?)

Tags: real-analysis

The definition I use for a limit of a function is the following:

> $\lim_{x\rightarrow c}f(x):=L$ if $\forall \epsilon>0, \exists \delta>0, \forall x\in \mathbb{R}^{\neq c}$, [ $|x-c|<\delta\implies|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$]

However, the video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=baqZdRZ1yJU&list=PLsT0BEyocS2K24uR64BhJpqEvbJFSxtAZ) gets rid of the requirement that $x\neq c$ and just writes $\forall x\in \mathbb{R}$. It even proves the limit is well-defined in the sense that this definition is unique [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F9-SLcjAWSI&t=210s).

$\textbf{Question:}$ What is the reason that we require $x\neq c$ in the first definition and not the second? It seems unnecessary and I feel like I am missing something. There has got to be a reason why $x\neq c$ here.

Comment: See [Limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_function#Functions_of_a_single_variable): you are right, the restriction is not necessary

Comment: But see also [Deleted versus non-deleted limits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_function#Deleted_versus_non-deleted_limits)

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I get it now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deletion is necessary for the following reasons:

1. If you don't delete the point of consideration, you cannot define limit of a function at a point outside its domain. For example, consider
   \begin{align*}
   f\colon \mathbb R\setminus\{1\}&\to\{1\}\\
   x&\mapsto 1\end{align*}
   We want to say that $\lim\limits_{x\to1}f(x)=1$, but we can't say that using the undeleted definition.
2. Also, if you use the undeleted definition, the limit of a function at a point has to be the value of the function at that point, if it exists. Suppose the limit exists, then
   $$\forall \varepsilon>0\exists\delta>0:|x-c|<\delta\implies |f(x)-L|<\varepsilon$$
   Taking $x=c$, the first condition is satisfied, and therefore by the implication, we get
   $$|f(c)-L|<\varepsilon\forall\varepsilon>0$$
   which implies $L=f(c)$.